# When programatically setting a set type filter, the floating filter box isn't updated

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When I use the selectvalue API to programatically control a set based filter, the floating filter window doesn't update.

If you select and deselect from the floating filter window manually it works fine.

See https://plnkr.co/edit/707g7FHCPOOi26AlUpyn?p=preview

Click on the API: Filter only John Joe Nevin and Kenny Egan and it will filter correctly but the floating filter box for Athlete is empty.

If you open the funnel next to it the filter is correct.  Unselect something and select something else and the athletes name comes up correctly in the floating filter input box.

Am I missing something?

```
//Code used to perform the filter.
var athleteFilterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance("athlete");
athleteFilterComponent.selectNothing();
athleteFilterComponent.selectValue("John Joe Nevin");
athleteFilterComponent.selectValue("Kenny Egan");
this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();

//Turn this option on as well.
floatingFilter='true'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in ag-grid.
However the workaround is to use `setModel()` api . Something like this worked -

```
  selectJohnAndKenny() {
    var athleteFilterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance("athlete");
    athleteFilterComponent.selectNothing();
    var model = ["John Joe Nevin", "Kenny Egan"];
    athleteFilterComponent.setModel(model);
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Pratik,  This does sometimes appear to work. 
 However when you clear the filter with selectNothing() again it leaves the values selected in there. https://plnkr.co/edit/707g7FHCPOOi26AlUpyn?p=preview